# How to create a geometry_msgs::Point?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS melodic.

I'm trying this C++ code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h"
#include "tf/transform_datatypes.h"
#include "tf/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>

// ... More code

geometry_msgs::Point p;
```

But I get the following error message:

```
no instance of constructor "geometry_msgs::Point_::Point_ [with ContainerAllocator=std::allocator]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (double, double)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327479/how-to-create-a-geometry_msgs::point?/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to include the [geometry_msgs/Point](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html) message, which resides in the geometry_msgs package. This is a header generated automatically from the Point.msg file in that package.

```
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
```

Also dont forget to add the geometry_msgs in your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt
In package.xml add:

```
<depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
```

In CMakeLists.txt add:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs
)
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3